# How to pause a video when scrolling?

Tags: javascript

I have a video with the following code.

```
 <iframe  id="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VEmS-bkdlZQ?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The website I'm building is a one-page website, and the idea is that once you scroll/navigate away from the front page the video should stop, I've tried

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll > 300) {
        $("#video").player.pause()
    }else{
        $('#video').player.play()
    }
});
```

Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work?
[Example here](http://skmo.nu/test99)

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't check your javascript console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined`. Essentially, `$('#video').player` is undefined.

Comment: I'm still relatively new to javascript, and I'm not really sure what is undefined. I've called my video by the proper tag, and from what I've read .player.pause() was the way to pause a video.

Comment: `$('#video')` is an iframe - it doesn't magically have a `player` property - you need to add that somehow. Read up about [the youtube JS api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) and the [playback control](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_controls) methods. There's also an [example here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo).